# SSRS report viewer for HTML5

Tags: html, reporting-services, reportviewer

We are using a web application in html5 and I want to integrate the developed ssrs reports into it. I want to create a report viewer for displaying the reports in my web application. I do not want to use .aspx page or any mvc page. I want the report viewer in html5.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.forerunnersw.com/

Comment: i dont want any third party tool

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds to me as if you are requesting that Microsoft add a .NET library or some "embeddable control" that you can put into an html5 project. Currently, I do not believe that there is a control for displaying the reports in html5 as you are requesting. You must use a work around as suggested by Coder of Code.

You can also look to these threads which basically say the same thing:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/7613447b-3590-4494-a94a-498af49f85dc/does-ssrs-2012-support-html5-and-dynamic-position

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to show the HTML render of a report and you want it to look like a native object to the application without any parameters or toolbar, then you could call the URL for the report directly and include "&rc:Toolbar=false" in the URL. This will hide the toolbar for the Report Viewer control. This method is described under the URL Access Parameter [Reference msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx). Not exactly what you asked for, but it may achieve the purpose.
You can use the `Reporting server's` URL for your report as it returns the data in the HTML format and show that that in the `IFrame` in HTML. I never did it but this approach can work by setting the `Iframes` URL as the reporting servers URL which will be something like this,

```
  http://ServerName/ReportServer?%2fSome+Folder%2fSome+Report+Name&rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=false&rc:HTMLFragment=true
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...... But i am looking for the html5 report viewer control for displaying reports in my application